# Firebase: Node.js: Find the difference in two map objects (added or modified)

Tags: node.js, firebase, google-cloud-firestore

What is the best way to find the difference in two map object in node.js.

My map looks like this

```
roles
   4K5EB8uP0G0OVWKK4YFe: "member"
   4OLEnMBAwhHL4agFD1bL: "initiate"
   Sg0igJdOusnOaDsjDGAY: "admin"
   ZQH29nwMnyHqdQvRgwd0: "initiate"
   hqmXu2I7ehhX9NyfmfdC: "initiate"
   nWX51v4HxCnznkK03rne: "initiate"
```

What can happen?

- A new line could be added (with whatever role)
- An existing line could be modified (key would stay the same but the value would modify to whatever)
  There is not the case that a line gets deleted (at least not yet). Deleting would be modifiying a role to "deleted"

```
.onUpdate((change, context) => {
        const beforeUpdate = change.before.data();
        const afterUpdate = change.after.data();
        const rolesBefore = beforeUpdate!.roles
        const rolesAfter = afterUpdate!.roles

        for (let [userId, userRole] of Object.entries(rolesAfter)) {
            if(userRole !== rolesBefore[userId]){
                //Now here a role is either missing or was updated?
                //How to determine what exactly happened? Is a missing entry undefined or null?
            }
        }
```

Will this work or is there even a 'diff' method in node.js?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `Array.filter` to find the differences between `afterUpdate` and `beforeUpdate` something like this:

```
// this one keeps all the afterUpdate keys that are not in the befoteUpdate
const addedKeys = Object.keys(afterUpdate).filter(key => !beforeUpdate[key])
// this one keeps all the afterUpdate keys related to an updated value
const modifiedKeys = Object.keys(afterUpdate).filter(key => beforeUpdate[key] && beforeUpdate[key] !== afterUpdate[key])
// note this second one excludes the afterUpdate keys that are not in the beforeUpdate because they aleady are in the addedKeys
```

to obtain values you can to `const addedValues = addedKeys.map(key => afterUpdate[key])`